# pytrends fail to get US City level data

Tags: python-3.x, api

According to the API Doc from https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends that interest_by_region has city parameter, so that what i want is to get California, Texas with keyword Corona Virus from 15-Jan-2020 to 15-Feb-2020

```
searchkey = ['Corona Virus']
city =['California','Texas']
region = pytrend.interest_by_region(resolution='CITY', inc_low_vol=True, inc_geo_code=True)
```

then i receive below error

```
KeyError: "['geoCode'] not in index"
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below link and make changes to the "**lib\site-packages\pytrends\request.py**" file in your directory.

link: [KeyError: "['geoCode'] not in index" #316](https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends/issues/316)

It wokred for me.

```
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US',geo = 'US', tz=360)
data = pytrend.interest_by_region(resolution='CITY', inc_low_vol=True,inc_geo_code=False)
```

Note: Once you change the code keep the **inc_geo_code as False**